# Keyword Driven framework (selenium with java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, frameworks, keyword

I have configured my code with log4j when i execute my Driverscript main class file,I'm getting an Error in log when driverscript is executed need a solution to it, all the codes are mentioned below with OR.txt(which contain object repository)

**DriverScript.java** (main class file)

```
package executionEngine;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;`enter code here`
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import config.ActionKeywords;
import config.Constants;
import utility.ExcelUtils;
import utility.Log;

public class DriverScript {

    public static Properties OR;
    public static ActionKeywords actionKeywords;
    public static String sActionKeyword;
    public static String sPageObject;
    public static Method method[];
    public static int iTestStep;
    public static int iTestLastStep;
    public static String sTestCaseID;
    public static String sRunMode;
    public static String sData;
    public static boolean bResult;

    public DriverScript() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
        actionKeywords = new ActionKeywords();
        method = actionKeywords.getClass().getMethods();        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constants.Path_TestData);
        DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
        String Path_OR = Constants.Path_OR;
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(Path_OR);
        OR= new Properties(System.getProperties());
        OR.load(fs);

        DriverScript startEngine = new DriverScript();
        startEngine.execute_TestCase();
    }

    private void execute_TestCase() throws Exception {
            int iTotalTestCases = ExcelUtils.getRowCount(Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
            for(int iTestcase=1;iTestcase<iTotalTestCases;iTestcase++){
                bResult = true;
                sTestCaseID = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestcase, Constants.Col_TestCaseID, Constants.Sheet_TestCases); 
                sRunMode = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestcase, Constants.Col_RunMode,Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
                if (sRunMode.equals("Yes")){
                    iTestStep = ExcelUtils.getRowContains(sTestCaseID, Constants.Col_TestCaseID, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                    iTestLastStep = ExcelUtils.getTestStepsCount(Constants.Sheet_TestSteps, sTestCaseID, iTestStep);
                    Log.startTestCase(sTestCaseID);
                    bResult=true;
                    for (;iTestStep<iTestLastStep;iTestStep++){
                        sActionKeyword = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestStep, Constants.Col_ActionKeyword,Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                        sPageObject = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestStep, Constants.Col_PageObject, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                        //Now we will use the data value and pass it to the methods
                        sData = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestStep, Constants.Col_DataSet, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                        execute_Actions();
                        if(bResult==false){
                            ExcelUtils.setCellData(Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL,iTestcase,Constants.Col_Result,Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
                            Log.endTestCase(sTestCaseID);
                            break;
                            }
                        }
                    if(bResult==true){
                    ExcelUtils.setCellData(Constants.KEYWORD_PASS,iTestcase,Constants.Col_Result,Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
                    Log.endTestCase(sTestCaseID);   
                        }

                    }

                }
            }   

     private static void execute_Actions() throws Exception {

        for(int i=0;i<method.length;i++){

            if(method[i].getName().equals(sActionKeyword)){
                //This code will pass three parameters to every invoke method
                method[i].invoke(actionKeywords,sPageObject, sData);
                if(bResult==true){
                    ExcelUtils.setCellData(Constants.KEYWORD_PASS, iTestStep, Constants.Col_TestStepResult, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                    break;
                }else{
                    ExcelUtils.setCellData(Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL, iTestStep, Constants.Col_TestStepResult, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                    ActionKeywords.closeBrowser("","");
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
     }

}







**ActionKeywords.java**(Action class)

package config;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static executionEngine.DriverScript.OR;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import executionEngine.DriverScript;
import utility.Log;

public class ActionKeywords {

        public static WebDriver driver;
    //This block of code will decide which browser type to start
    public static void openBrowser(String object,String data){      
        Log.info("Opening Browser");
        try{
            //If value of the parameter is Mozilla, this will execute
            if(data.equals("Mozilla")){
                driver=new FirefoxDriver();
                Log.info("Mozilla browser started");
                }
            else if(data.equals("IE")){
                //You may need to change the code here to start IE Driver
                driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
                Log.info("IE browser started");
                }
            else if(data.equals("Chrome")){
                driver=new ChromeDriver();
                Log.info("Chrome browser started");
                }

            int implicitWaitTime=(10);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(implicitWaitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.info("Not able to open the Browser --- " + e.getMessage());
            DriverScript.bResult = false;
        }
    }

    public static void navigate(String object, String data){
        try{
            Log.info("Navigating to URL");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //Constant Variable is used in place of URL
            driver.get(Constants.URL);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.info("Not able to navigate --- " + e.getMessage());
            DriverScript.bResult = false;
            }
        }

    public static void click(String object, String data){
        try{
            Log.info("Clicking on Webelement "+ object);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).click();
         }catch(Exception e){
            Log.error("Not able to click --- " + e.getMessage());
            DriverScript.bResult = false;
            }
        }
    //Now this method accepts two value (Object name & Data)
    public static void input(String object, String data){
        try{
            Log.info("Entering the text in " + object);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).sendKeys(data);
         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.error("Not able to Enter UserName --- " + e.getMessage());
             DriverScript.bResult = false;
            }
        }

    public static void waitFor(String object, String data) throws Exception{
        try{
            Log.info("Wait for 5 seconds");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.error("Not able to Wait --- " + e.getMessage());
             DriverScript.bResult = false;
            }
        }

    public static void closeBrowser(String object, String data){
        try{
            Log.info("Closing the browser");
            driver.quit();
         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.error("Not able to Close the Browser --- " + e.getMessage());
             DriverScript.bResult = false;
            }
        }

    }




**Constants.java**(constants are declared here)

package config;

public class Constants {

    //List of System Variables
    public static final String URL = "http://www.store.demoqa.com";
    //public static final String Path_TestData = "D://Tools QA Projects//trunk//Hybrid KeyWord Driven//src//dataEngine//DataEngine.xlsx";
    //public static final String Path_OR = "D://Tools QA Projects//trunk//Hybrid KeyWord Driven//src//config//OR.txt";
    public static final String Path_TestData = "C:/Users/imaz/workspace/KeywordDriven Framework/src/dataEngine/DataEngine.xlsx";
    public static final String Path_OR = "C:/Users/imaz/workspace/KeywordDriven Framework/src/config/OR.txt";

    public static final String File_TestData = "DataEngine.xlsx";
    public static final int Col_Result =3 ;
    public static final int Col_TestStepResult =6 ;
    public static final String KEYWORD_FAIL = "FAIL";
    public static final String KEYWORD_PASS = "PASS";
    //List of Data Sheet Column Numbers
    public static final int Col_TestCaseID = 0; 
    public static final int Col_TestScenarioID =1 ;
    public static final int Col_PageObject =3 ;
    public static final int Col_ActionKeyword =4 ;
    public static final int Col_DataSet =5 ;
    //public static final int Col_TestStepResult =6 ;
    //New entry in Constant variable
    public static final int Col_RunMode =2 ;

    //List of Data Engine Excel sheets
    public static final String Sheet_TestSteps = "Test Steps";
    //New entry in Constant variable
    public static final String Sheet_TestCases = "Test Cases";

    //List of Test Data
    public static final String UserName = "testuser_3";
    public static final String Password = "Test@123";

}


**ExcelUtils**(excel utility class)

package utility;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;

import config.Constants;
import executionEngine.DriverScript;
    public class ExcelUtils {
            private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
            private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
            private static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell Cell;
            private static XSSFRow Row;



        public static void setExcelFile(String Path) throws Exception {
            try {
                FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
                ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.error("Class Utils | Method setExcelFile | Exception desc : "+e.getMessage());
                DriverScript.bResult = false;
                }
            }

        public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum, String SheetName ) throws Exception{
            try{
                ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
                Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
                String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
                return CellData;
             }catch (Exception e){
                 Log.error("Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : "+e.getMessage());
                 DriverScript.bResult = false;
                 return"";
                 }
             }




        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        //This method is use to write value in the excel sheet
        //This method accepts four arguments (Result, Row Number, Column Number & Sheet Name)
        public static void setCellData(String Result,  int RowNum, int ColNum, String SheetName) throws Exception    {
               try{

                   ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
                   Row  = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);
                   Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                   if (Cell == null) {
                       Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum);
                       Cell.setCellValue(Result);
                   } else {
                        Cell.setCellValue(Result);
                        }
                    // Constant variables Test Data path and Test Data file name
                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Constants.Path_TestData);
                    ExcelWBook.write(fileOut);
                    //fileOut.flush();
                    fileOut.close();
                    ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(Constants.Path_TestData));
                 }catch(Exception e){
                    DriverScript.bResult = false;
                    }
                }

        public static int getRowCount(String SheetName){
            int iNumber=0;
            try {
                ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
                iNumber=ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.error("Class Utils | Method getRowCount | Exception desc : "+e.getMessage());
                DriverScript.bResult = false;
                }
            return iNumber;
            }

        public static int getRowContains(String sTestCaseName, int colNum,String SheetName) throws Exception{
            int iRowNum=0;  
            try {
                //ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
                int rowCount = ExcelUtils.getRowCount(SheetName);
                for (; iRowNum<rowCount; iRowNum++){
                    if  (ExcelUtils.getCellData(iRowNum,colNum,SheetName).equalsIgnoreCase(sTestCaseName)){
                        break;
                    }
                }                   
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.error("Class Utils | Method getRowContains | Exception desc : "+e.getMessage());
                DriverScript.bResult = false;
                }
            return iRowNum;
            }

        public static int getTestStepsCount(String SheetName, String sTestCaseID, int iTestCaseStart) throws Exception{
            try {
                for(int i=iTestCaseStart;i<=ExcelUtils.getRowCount(SheetName);i++){
                    if(!sTestCaseID.equals(ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, Constants.Col_TestCaseID, SheetName))){
                        int number = i;
                        return number;                      
                        }
                    }
                ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
                int number=ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
                return number;
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.error("Class Utils | Method getRowContains | Exception desc : "+e.getMessage());
                DriverScript.bResult = false;
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }

**log(log class)**

package utility;

        import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    public class Log {

        //Initialize Log4j logs
        private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName());//

    // This is to print log for the beginning of the test case, as we usually run so many test cases as a test suite
    public static void startTestCase(String sTestCaseName){

       Log.info("****************************************************************************************");
       Log.info("****************************************************************************************");
       Log.info("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$                 "+sTestCaseName+ "       $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
       Log.info("****************************************************************************************");
       Log.info("****************************************************************************************");

       }

    //This is to print log for the ending of the test case
    public static void endTestCase(String sTestCaseName){
       Log.info("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX             "+"-E---N---D-"+"             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
       Log.info("X");
       Log.info("X");
       Log.info("X");
       Log.info("X");

       }

    // Need to create these methods, so that they can be called  
    public static void info(String message) {
           Log.info(message);
           }

    public static void warn(String message) {
       Log.warn(message);
       }

    public static void error(String message) {
       Log.error(message);
       }

    public static void fatal(String message) {
       Log.fatal(message);
       }

    public static void debug(String message) {
       Log.debug(message);
       }

    }



**log4j.xml**(configuration)

<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">

<param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />

<param name="File" value="logfile.log"/>

<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">

<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m %n" />

</layout>

</appender>

<root>

<level value="INFO"/>

<appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>

</root>

</log4j:configuration>




**Error displayed on the log when driverscript is executed**

2015-08-05 19:25:07,344 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,345 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,345 INFO  [Log] $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$                 LogIn_01       $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,345 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,345 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,503 INFO  [Log] XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX             -E---N---D-             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,503 INFO  [Log] X 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,503 INFO  [Log] X 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,503 INFO  [Log] X 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,503 INFO  [Log] X 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,504 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,504 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,504 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,504 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,504 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,504 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,504 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,504 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,504 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,505 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,506 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,507 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,507 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,509 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,510 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 ERROR [Log] Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception description : null 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 INFO  [Log] $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$                 LogIn_01       $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,511 INFO  [Log] **************************************************************************************** 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,579 INFO  [Log] XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX             -E---N---D-             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,579 INFO  [Log] X 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,579 INFO  [Log] X 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,579 INFO  [Log] X 
2015-08-05 19:25:07,579 INFO  [Log] X 


**OR.txt(object repository)**
# Home Page Objects
btn_MyAccount=.//*[@id='account']/a
btn_LogOut=.//*[@id='account_logout']

# Login Page Object
txtbx_UserName=.//*[@id='log']
txtbx_Password=.//*[@id='pwd']
btn_LogIn=.//*[@id='login']
```

Comment: Please reduce your question to an [mcve]